# Can we talk about Minecraft Mods?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, minecraft, game-modifications

Some mods aren't fully completed in Minecraft so there are many questions to be asked. Is it okay to ask these questions or do they go under a category of "Don't ask these questions"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can say is try. Hopefully there is an answer, but if the thing itself is not finished, you run the risk of there not being a clear answer, or it being something only the developers can answer, which means it is something we won't be able to help with.

As always, the more detail and clarity there is in your question, the better chance you have of a good answer.  Tell us everything you can - what mod, what version, anything you have tried, whatever you can think of that might help us help you.

Comment: @YoungGuilo yes you can ask about mods, however, [You can't ask about technical support of Minecraft Mods. You can find more info on this link](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no?lq=1).